# "Just" vs "already": which one is sooner?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Which one is sooner or closer to now?

> 1. I've just called him.
> 2. I've already called him.

Comment: I'll note that in your context, "sooner" and "closer to now" are opposites. *Already* is sooner, *just* is closer to now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Just" implies that it happened immediately before you spoke. "Already" refers to some unspecific time in the past.

Answer (score 5):

> Just

put the emphasis on when you did (in the very near past)

> Already

put the emphasis on the fact that you actually did.
It could mean "No need to worry about it, I already did it", or it could mean "you are late, I already did it." for example

Answer (score 3):

When one say:

> I've just called him

It means it was done at the moment immediately before saying it. On the other hand:

> I've already called him

only implies that it was done before, without being specific as when exactly it was done.